# Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser() is returning null

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom module in my magento (version 1.5) and it's meant to load the currently logged in admin username like this in one of my controller:

```
$current_user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
if ($current_user) {
    $this->current_user = $current_user->getUsername();
} else {
    $this->current_user = '';
}
```

When the code runs, `$this->current_user` is empty, so I did a `var_dump($current_user); exit();` and it appears to be `null` akways (even if I am logged in).

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Try if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) { //write your code here //}

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
//verify if the user is logged in to the backend
if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  echo "Admin Logged in";
}
else
{
  echo "You need to be logged in as an admin.";
}
```